# Xubuntu entry stuck in BIOS

Tags: usb-drive, xubuntu, firmware

So I tried to use ra1nstorm today (if you don’t know what that is, it’s a tool that installs Xubuntu to run using an installer from within Windows, which makes a partition creating the install image), but something went wrong. Xubuntu refused to boot. Luckily none of my other OSes were touched. I attempted to install it to a 29.3 GB external USB flash drive, but it placed an entry in the BIOS to boot it, and it was in my fist (very internal) drive. I now have a useless firmware entry to install Xubuntu which doesn’t work whether I have my flash drive in it or not. If it is in there, it will load the installer screen, telling my I don’t have an ESP partition until I click “Continue” instead of “Go Back”, and then it just hangs indefinitely. If I don’t have it in, it just boots into a GRUB command line. How do I rid my machine of this entry?

Comment: "useless firmware entry" as in a UEFI boot manager entry? These can usually be manipulated by the UEFI BIOS.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. How do I use this to remove the entry?